# Good "One page documents" to take away everywhere

Tags: language-agnostic, metaprogramming

I'm a beginner when it comes to programming, and I have the nasty habit of googling anything I want to do, or don't understand. When I have to work offline it's of course really hard for me.

I'm trying to make a handbook out of any good cheat-sheet and refcards I've found.

So far I have a [Vi cheat sheet](http://www.viemu.com/vi-vim-cheat-sheet.gif), some docs from [Addedbytes](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/) and a few about standard OS commands.

The question is:
What documents are absolutely essential to avoid being useless while offline. (The more synthetic, the better)

Comment: Ultimately, I would say purchase some recommended books, too; seek council from many. On another note, I think this is off-topic and _may_ be a better fit on Programmers.SE.

Comment: I hope that many advice could be better than any book sold on the market. And about Programmers.SE, you're right, didn't think of it.

Comment: The big idea, though, is that you _learn_ this stuff, not just _mimic_ it.

Comment: I agree, but I often forget the exact name or number of parameters for whatever function I need to use. A really small doc can fix this kind of problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you want to lug around a whole binder of cheat-sheets (which then poses other problmes such as searching for the info), i'd recommend a usb key with the cheat-sheets regarding

- the OS you're working on
- the language you'll be working with
- the technologies you'll be building upon

If you really insist on being exhaustive, a site like http://www.cheat-sheets.org/ may help you go on a cheat-sheet splurge, and you may want to have a look at [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cheat-sheet) on stackoverflow